# How to set up an IF condition within mysql package in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, if-statement

I'm using `mysql` package for `node.js`

Studying the documentation did not help me with my question.
I want to make following:

```
if (SELECT table_field WHERE id = some_value ){
  // execute some code
} else{
  // execute some code
}
```

So I want `SELECT` to return either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (like `EXISTS` operator)

How can I do so with `node.js`?

Comment: Formatting things for better readability

Comment: Why not use EXISTS (as you mentioned). That's what it's there for

Answer (score 0):

After you setup your connection, you'll want to do something like this:

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "SELECT table_field WHERE id = some_value" // setup your query
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {  // pass your query
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Result: " + result);
    if (result) {
      // true logic
    }
    else
    {
      // false logic
    }
  });
});
```

You can't use the SQL query directly in the IF statement.  You need to retrieve the results and then use the results as the boolean value.